# Insert into my local sql server

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to insert into my local sqlserver. The problem is that it doesnt seems to run php code. It opens page in browser with all my code:

### Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
<title>Form linked to database</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="username">
<br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="insert">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Php

```
<?php
$servername = "(local)\sqlexpress";
$username = "sa";
$password = "1234";
$dbname = "MyCalendar";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "INSERT INTO customermaster(code, name, email)
VALUES ('1234', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

[image]
I'm begginer on this. Souldnt i take only the exception if something will go wrong?

Comment: I believe you will need a webserver capable of intepreting php codes. And mysqli extension as the name implies is specific to mysql db server

Comment: Ok, what if i will change (local)\sqlexpress in my pc dynamic ip-192.168.1.5,1433. I have the same problem. The thing is why i dont take only the exception? Connection failed:

Comment: http://localhost/ should go in server name?

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly open php files. You need to install a local server on your computer for your php codes to be executed. Try [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/tr/index.html) it is easy to install.

Comment: Did the xampp gives a server name, username,password and database name?

Comment: XAMPP comes with phpMyAdmin. which is very nice for creating databases. you can create as much database as you need. Also the mysql server inside xampp has "root" as username and no password by default.
your code should look like
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "WhatevetThename";

Answer (score 0):

You need to first set up a web server. [AppServ](https://www.appserv.org/en/) can recommend about it is simple and fast. Check the incoming POST when we come to your code.

Example :

```
if(extract($_POST)) {
   $sql = "INSERT INTO customermaster(code, name, email) VALUES ('1234', 'Doe', 'john@example.com')";

   if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
   } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
   }
 }
```

Also : After installation is complete in the url portion of the run, type http://localhost.

Comment: Are there default username and password and database name?

Comment: @testsc You decide during installation. The default database user name is root.

Comment: Ok thank you let me try it, and i will come back soon

Comment: I will help you if you have problems.